# How to add App.Config file in Visual web developer 2010?

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

How to add App.Config file to my console application project in Visual web developer 2010?

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

First add System.Configuration reference in your VS 2010. then add go to Add -> New item -> search for Configuration file which would have App.Config extention and then file would be added.

Comment: Neel Added System.Configuration reference but not showing config file in installed template.I am using Visual webdeveloper 2010.

Comment: Is not there any Application configuration file?

Comment: No i havn't seen Application configuration file in Visual web developer 2010.

Comment: That is not the case that ur using web developer ..the process is same for that also..i am wondering why ur not able to get configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts for me.